# Continuous Integration (Jenkins) with Grails and an inPlace Plugin

Tags: git, grails, groovy, jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to create an continuous integration environment for my grails application. 
My grails app depends on an inplace plugin. By now i used a simple shell script wich clones my two git repositories (one for grails app, one for the inplace plugin my grails app depends on) in the same folder and runs "grails prod war" to create the war file.

I could get the grails build working in jenkins (with grails plugin) but how can i configure jenkins to clone the second repository with my inplace plugin beside my main project so that the "grails prod war" process just uses the sources of the plugin too (because it's referred in BuildConfig.groovy)?

How can i get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. [Run your shell script in the Jenkins build.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-ShellScriptsandWindowsBatchCommands)
2. Declare your plugin as inline just in your development machine, but create a separated build for it in Jenkins. When building your application, define the correct version of the plugin, so Grails can get it from the local maven.

Comment: Hi Sergio, what do you think is the best solution of this two? Using the second option seems cleaner but then i have to increase the version number of my plugin, each time i make changes to it, or not? (Does Jenkins push the same version of the plugin each time it builds to the maven repository?) What would you choose?

Comment: If your plugin is used just by one application, use the 1. But if it's shared, it's better to control his version.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Jenkins [Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin).  As its name implies, it

> "Allows a job to check out sources from multiple SCM providers."

The plugin will allow you to add both of your git repos to the `Source Code Management` section of your job. You can configure where each git repo will be cloned within your workspace by setting `Advanced -> Local subdirectory for repo` for each git SCM.